# processing.js: save udp packets received as an array

Tags: java, udp, processing.js

I receive udp packets in processing.js to use them in my app. in the below code I extract the value I want , but the problem is in this way all of the data in first packet saved into (array) bin[0] , the second packet in bin[1] and ... while I want to separate the data of each packet. any idea how could I do that ?

please notice that this java code is written in processing.js which use hypermedia library for receiving packets!

this is the complete code :

```
void receive(byte[] data, String HOST_IP, int PORT_RX) {
  receivedFromUDP ="";
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    receivedFromUDP += str(data[i]) + " ";
int[] bin =new int[]{unbinary(binary(data[2*i+1])+binary(data[2*i]))};
println("bin is" + bin[0]);
  }
  //println(data);
}
```

and the output for print(bin[0]) is :

```
bin is4495
bin is50
bin is8250
bin is50
bin is6435
bin is310
bin is14800
bin is65406
bin is4485
bin is40
bin is25500
bin is10200
bin is4850
bin is65
bin is7415
bin is350
bin is25500
bin is62976
bin is25500
bin is62976
bin is25500
bin is62976
bin is25500
bin is62976
```

so all of this packet saved into bin[0] while I want to separate them !maybe the problem is that I receive the data here (  receivedFromUDP += str(data[i]) + " ";) as string ! how could I save the data into array here ?

2.my data is float but I  multiplied it to 100 to be able to send them easily , now could I convertint array to save this data which is float?

please notice that this udp library recieve data only in byte[].